# Is it possible to change an existing Order Status picklist value's Status Category?

Tags: picklist, order, status

Can I change Test Status' `Status Category` from Draft to Activated or vice versa?

[image: [![enter image description here][]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pt_5858,

Found the way to update them using vs code -

In your XML file retrieve the field as below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
     <types>
        <members>Order.Status</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
     <types>
        <members>Order</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types> 
        <members>OrderStatus</members> 
        <name>StandardValueSet</name> 
    </types>
    <version>54.0</version>
</Package>
```

When you retrieve it successfully you will see the standardValueSets folder as below -

[image]

Click on the file and edit the Group string for Test Status from -

```
 <groupingString>Draft</groupingString> to  <groupingString>Activated</groupingString>
```

[image]

Deploy this to your org and you are done..

Doc Reference to fetch standard value Set - [Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a straightforward way to change the status category.

Though you can try taking metadata retrieve of your picklist field in you vs code and change the status category and deploy it back to the org.

Else you can go ahead and create a new value and decide the status category by following the below steps.

In Classic:
Go to: Setup | Customize | "Your SObject"  | Fields.
Click on the Status field.
Click on the "New" button, enter the new Status and select the appropriate Status Category for this value.
Click "Save".

In Lightning:
Click the gear icon | Setup | Find the "Your SObject" object under Object Manager Tab
Hit "Fields & Relationships" | Click on the Status field
Click on the "New" button, enter the new Status and select the appropriate Status Category for this value.
Click "Save"

Comment: I've tried vs code but couldn't figure out to fetch/edit picklist values of an object, any resource or info can you share?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to be able to do the same thing. I've coincidentally discovered that if you deactivate the status you want to change. Create a new status with the same Label and API Name, but change the Status Category, it'll reactivate the status, but it will have the new Status Category :D

For example,
I created 'Pending Return' as 'Activated' and I have deactivated the status...

[image: Deactivated the status I want to change]

I will click 'New' and create a new status with the Label 'Pending Return', API Name 'Pending Return' and Status Category of 'Draft'

[image: Creating the New Status]

Boom! It is no longer in the 'Inactive Values' list, but it does have the 'Status Category' of 'Draft'.

[image: New Status with DRAFT category]

I hope this helps someone else :)